# Unable to make IntelliJ Idea 12 work with Scala compiler

Tags: scala, ubuntu, intellij-idea

I have installed Scala, sbt, eclipse and IntelliJ Idea 12. And also jdk, jre, etc. I'm able to run scala in Eclipse (Scala eclipse IDE) but I can't do it in Idea, even though I downloaded and installed scala plugin though Idea. Here is what I'm having at `File -> Setting`

[image: http://makescreen.ru/i/e1f7cdb3497610f9ff88a316a9f18c.jpg]

and at a new project creation page

[image: http://makescreen.ru/i/a658c10e66dd033a20852cbb6f28b3.jpg]

How do I solve these issues?

```
whereis scala
scala: /usr/bin/scala /usr/bin/X11/scala /usr/share/scala



 which scala
/usr/bin/scala
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I know I'm repeating this at any possible occasion—but your life will be much easier if you have sbt generate your IDEA project instead of trying to set it up manually. That will take care of configuring the modules correctly, so you are instantly ready to compile and run.

Here is [a blog entry](http://vyazici.blogspot.de/2012/11/setting-up-scala-development.html) that might help. The section "How can I integrate libraries installed by SBT to IDEA?" tells you how to generate the project files.

---

Basically you need to create—starting from the root directory of your project—the file `project/plugins.sbt` with the following content:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.github.mpeltonen" % "sbt-idea" % "1.4.0")
```

(you can also do that in the file `~/.sbt/plugins/build.sbt` instead, that way you have the plugin available for any of your projects)

Then you run `sbt gen-idea`, and afterwards you can open the project directly from IDEA through File -> Open Project (and pointing to the project's root directory).

Comment: but what if I use IntelliJ Idea 12 with SBT plugin "inside"?

Comment: These are two independent things—the sbt plugin for IDEA gives you sbt console + compiler from within IDEA. the IDEA plugin for sbt gives you the possibility to create an IDEA project from a standard sbt terminal invocation. Typically you will use both (at least I do)

Answer (score 1):

You could also generate your IDEA project with Gradle, which handles Scala+IDEA combination very well. Here's a minimal `build.gradle` script to do this:

```
apply plugin: 'scala'
apply plugin: 'idea'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.10.1'
}
```

Just create a directory for your project, put `build.gradle` inside it, create `src/main/scala` subdirectory, then install Gradle and run `gradle idea` inside your project's directory. That should generate nicely configured IDEA project. With this method you don't even need to install Scala.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly your problem is? I don't see anything on your screens which prevents you from using Scala in IDEA. Just select "Set Scala Home" radiobutton in "New project" dialog and then select your Scala installation path (I guess it will be /usr/share/scala). IDEA then will automatically create library and compiler libraries and add Scala facet to your project.

Comment: I did it. But `File -> Setting -> Scala compiler` is still empty.

Comment: @AlanDert And? Why you need it to be not empty?

Comment: Вовка, для того, чтобы задать настройки.

Comment: @AlanDert Which settings exactly? As far as I know, all of the compiler settings are set in "Project structure" dialog in Scala facet options: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B90ilMJQfjp6OVN5N0NJWGNYOGc/edit?usp=sharing